# Bind value to ruby define_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model, I'm trying to dynamically expose objects that are inside an array as a top level attribute. Here's the code snippet:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessor :name
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
  #attr_accessor :widgets

  after_initialize :init_widgets

  def init_widgets
    widgets
    widgets.each_with_index do |widget, index|
      define_method(widget.name) do
        widgets[index]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way for me to define the value of index into the new method I am creating so that it will be associated with the proper index?

Comment: There might be better ways of doing things.  If you are referring to `has_many :widgets` as `array` then that must be corrected. Secondly, I would not advise your `after_initialize` block for what it is doing because `after_initialize` gets called everywhere, initialization, Active Record's finders etc. Could you add more information to your problem?

Comment: By default, you can access `my_model.widgets[0]`, `my_model.widgets[1]`, `my_model.widgets.last` etc. - is there anything missing in that way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

I might create an accessor / assignment methods that overload the `[]` operator:

```
class BracketOperator
  def initialize
    @values = (1..100).to_a
  end

  def [](index)
    @values[index]
  end

  def []=(index, value)
    @values[index] = value
  end
 end

 bo = BracketOperator.new
 bo[3] # => 4
 bo[3] = 17
 bo[3] # => 17
```

Answer (score 0):

So for reference, here's the answer I came up with. Apparently I don't understand scoping for ruby too well. The variable `n` somehow remains referenced to the n within the each loop. Hence for my original question, I can just use the `index` variable within the method and it will be mapped to what I am expecting it to be mapped to.

```
 class Test
   def setup
     names = [ "foo","bar" ] 
     names.each do |n|
       self.class.send :define_method, n do
         puts "method is called #{n}!"
       end
     end
   end
 end
```